# Change margins in a0poster class

Tags: margins

I want to make a poster using the a0poster package. I want to modify the text margins, so the text should be wider. I'm using boxes in a portrait, three column poster, but I have problem trying to get boxes bigger (one white page and after the text). Thanks

Comment: No results modifying the value of `\textwidth`?

Comment: I mean something like `\addtolength{\textwidth}{1cm}`

Comment: Done!..thanks!..I was thinking taht could be more difficult (change the .cls file or something). Thanks again!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can simply increase the width of the text in the page adding the line:

```
\addtolength{\textwidth}{1cm}
```

If 1cm is not enough or too much, change it to your needs.

Comment: Done!!..thank you...I was thinking that in that a0poster class I will need to modify the .cls file. Thanks again!

Comment: There is one inconvenient in this answer, it only reduces the right margin, due to the longer lines. The left margin remains the same.